# Help me choose the best filesystem for my PC

Tags: filesystem, 15.10

I'm going to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 on my notebook so i'd like to know which filesystem is the best for me.

It's an Acer Aspire E5-511 with 4GB RAM , Intel HD Graphics and a Intel Celeron N2840 @2.19Ghz (2.55 turbo mode) with a 500GB HDD (not too powerful but it does it's job). I mostly use my pc for gaming and video production.

I did my researches but I can't decide.

Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: If in doubt, go with the defaults ( Ext 4 )

Comment: You haven't mentioned any reason why the default is not suitable, or given any specific requirements (gaming and video production do not require any special setup), so I don't see any other option but to recommend just using the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ext4 file system is recommended for all Linux operating systems because has  backwards compatibility with its predecessors, you can mount Ext2 and Ext3 as an Ext4 file system

### Ext4

- reduces file fragmentation
- employs delayed allocation which helps with flash memory life as well as fragmentation.
- Good choice for SSDs and HDD

### BtrFS

- it allows for drive pooling, on the fly snapshots
- transparent compression
- online defragmentation
- it’s not stable in some distros

### ReiserFS

- Has great performance for small files such as logs and is suited for databases and email servers.
- ReiserFS can be dynamically expanded but not shrunk and does not support FS level encryption.

### XFS

- Good for a media file server because of constant throughput for large files.
- Most distributions require separate /boot partition because XFS and GRUB can be unpredictable
- Performance with small files is not as good.

### JFS

- Good performance for both large and small files and because of its low CPU usage is probably best for low powered servers and computers
- It does not have built in tools for drive pooling
- It also has fast disk checking compared to Ext but there have been some reports of disk corruption after long term use.

### ZFS

- Shows great performance in large disk arrays.
- Supports a lot of advanced features including drive pooling, snapshots, and dynamic disk striping.
- It may be difficult to install in Linux because it requires FUSE and might not be supported by your distribution.

More info found [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33552/htg-explains-which-linux-file-system-should-you-choose/)

Comment: Probably worth noting a few things. ReiserFS showed promise a decade ago but has an uncertain future as its next version, Reiser4, has failed to gain acceptance by Linux kernel (and its former developer was convicted of murder). A lot of people love the idea of BTRFS but even in late 2017 it's still not stable enough for me to recommend (they claim it's stable, and it's packaged for distros, but there's a long, long list of edge conditions that might result in data corruption). JFS is good but generally not seen as enough of an improvement over EXT4 on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

**Just use the default (ext4)**

You have not mentioned any specific requirements, or given any reasons why the defaults would not be suitable.  The defaults are carefully chosen and proven to work, so you don't have to worry.

Varying your setup from the default, especially something as fundamental as the filesystem, is unnecessary unless you know you have specific technical requirements, and you would have to be doing something pretty specialised with your system rather than just normal everyday tasks.  For example, running a high-availability database cluster, or something.